# FFMPEG: How to copy metadata from a video file to an AVI video file?

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to keep metadata of rotation along with other information of any input file to output of AVI container. I've already tried adding following parameters

> `-metadata:s:v rotate="90"`, `-map_metadata 0`, `-movflags use_metadata_tags`,  `-map_metadata 0:g`

but nothing works for AVI output.
`-metadata:s:v rotate="90"` is working for mkv, mp4 files but AVI ouput doesn't contain any metadata of input. What am I missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: ffmpeg only writes title and language for AVIs.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any way to keep video rotation while copying the video stream for AVIs?